# I'm building a Wallpaper Changer Java application, having issues with BATCH refreshing the desktop wallpaper

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, wallpaper

The basic idea of the application is creating an image with a custom color background and a PNG picture. The whole Java part creates the combined PNG file and exports it to *back.png*.

Then it would run a *set.bat* file, which is used to convert the PNG to JPG and set it as Desktop Wallpaper for Windows.

The problem is that the process only works when Java creates the PNG and I start *set.bat* manually from Windows Explorer. If the Java application starts it, the PNG is converted to JPG, the registry is changed, but it isn't refreshed.

Set.bat:

```
magick "<censored>\back.png" "<censored>\back.jpg"
echo Yes|reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d <censored>\back.jpg
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True
```

Java code snippet which should run *set.bat*:

```
try {
        System.out.println("Converting to JPG and setting wallpaper (set.bat)");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",path+"set.bat");
        Process p = pb.start();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I also tried Runtime execute in Java, but it did the same thing.

The process works in my opinion, but a change is needed to have the desktop refreshed.

Comment: https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/06/changewallpaper.html

Comment: might help if you  add `waitFor` for the process to finish  - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it needs some time, I separated each command in the batch and I call them after each other. The Update command is Delayed by 2 seconds. It seems to be working now.